# Featured tag not working?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, sidebar, featured-questions

I was just checking up on meta and noticed only the "This answer is a stub..." question listed under the "Featured on Meta" section. I clicked the featured tag thinking it was weird there was only one featured post, and found another one tagged but not displayed.

As you can see 2 questions are tagged featured, but only one of them shows up in the side bar. Bug? Is it a timing thing? I've refreshed a few times; but maybe it takes time for featured tag "to work"?

[image: Screen shot of the Featured Tag filter page]

Comment: Removing and re-adding the featured tag on the burninate question makes it show up in the "Featured on Meta" section, so apparently the Featured tag has a shelf life.

Comment: @RobertHarvey weird, any idea what that time frame is?

Comment: I don't know the exact time frame.  But it makes sense to expire the notification after awhile.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It does make sense, can the featured tag not be automatically removed when it expires?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable [feature-request]

Comment: @RobertHarvey created and linked =D

Comment: Please don't reference the -110 vote question. It is a new feature, but it is both declined and accepted.

Comment: @Zixuan What do you mean? Culyx is reporting a bug with a disconnect between questions that are tagged featured and those that appear in the "Featured on Meta" list. The only reference to that question you're asking not be referenced is the fact that it was featured at the moment this bug was observed. That's necessary to report the bug. Even if it weren't, your reason for not referencing doesn't make any sense in this context, because it's not talking about the content of the featured posts at all.

Comment: I mean that the question, that you have a answer to (no offense), is declined by some people and accepted by others.

Comment: @Zixuan Yes, what you are saying is true. But it doesn't make any sense in this context. Why does the content of that question matter for this bug report?

Comment: I know it doesn't matter, but I would not want if I asked a question on Meta to reference any other questions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "But it makes sense to expire the notification after awhile. " It looks a bit as if the whole new HNQ/feature thing is a misuse of tags. Maybe it should be a flag instead of a tag. Flags age away after some time. Tags usually do not.

Comment: Before people get upset about the reversal in dupe targets - the other one has an answer - collaborated by moderator and CM.